# How to fix block to the bottom of the view and stop it extending longer than viewport when empty

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a block with a small amount of text and a color fill that needs to stretch to the bottom of the viewport. Only if the text (content) is not visible on a small device should there be any need to scroll.

Currently I am getting this long scrollable empty div. Somehow I need this to only scroll to show the content if hidden.

I am thinking this is a calculation. Can anybody help.

[Div scrolls until it is 100% filling the viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBJ6s.jpg)

```css
.bottom-detail {
  // position:absolute;
  background-color: var(--ion-color-primary);
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.primary-b-shape {
  width: 100%;
  img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="primary-b-shape"><img src="../assets/primary-b-shape.svg"></div>
<div class="ion-text-center bottom-detail">
  <p class="text-small">Already a myStorytime listener?</p>
  <a class="secondary-link" href="#">
    <h5>Sign in</h5>
  </a>
</div>
```

I expect the .bottom-detail to only be as long as the viewport. Currently scrolling unnecessarily

[This is all that should be visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrXSz.jpg)

[With no height attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD6X8.jpg)

Comment: you should subtract the height of `primary-b-shape` from the `height: 100%;` and you should get your desired result. it goes like `height: calc(100% - Wpx);` where W is the height of `primary-b-shape`.

Comment: `ion-content { --overflow: hidden; }` and then try using your element and css in the page

Comment: Thanks  Mohan Gopi this does work, however, I need the overflow to be visible on small devices.

Comment: @Joykal Infotech Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I still have to try it.